# Why would oscillation of a gas column inhibit rather than promote mixing?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, resonance, diffusion

Many years ago I helped to support an experiment conducted in Japan which investigated the effects of [high frequency oscillation ventilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-frequency_ventilation) (HFOV) on the mixing and distribution of gas into the lungs.

But this experiment rather simplified the system by using a simple horizontal tube, perhaps 2 meters in length. At one end of the tube a plenum was placed, and at the other, an HFOV ventilator. Initially the system was filled with air. An oxygen cell was placed in the plenum to measure the $O_2$ concentration. At the start of each experiment, a small volume (maybe 500 mL) of pure oxygen was introduced slowly at the end where the HFOV ventilator was attached.

Although I can't recall all the details of the experiment, I do remember one result that's left me baffled all these years. The following two experiments:

(1) After introducing the oxygen the system was left unpowered so that natural diffusion would occur.
(2) After introducing the oxygen, the HFOV ventilator was turned on and allowed to oscillate the gas column

Note that oscillating the gas column with the ventilator results in no net displacement of the gas. Perhaps only 100 mL back and forth displacement. And the volume of the full tube is significantly larger than the volume of the introduced oxygen.The HFOV machine was able to oscillate at frequencies between 4 and 20 Hz.

The expected result would be that the oscillations would promote the movement of the oxygen towards the plenum. But the opposite, confounding result occurred. The oscillations actually inhibited the movement of the oxygen by a significant time.

I'm guessing now but diffusion maybe took an hour without oscillation. But with oscillation it took maybe 30 minutes longer.

So my question: are there any known physical properties of oscillating flow that could explain such a result?

I tried researching to see if the work was ever published, but no luck. The physician I worked with was a Dr. Miao.

Comment: How would a standing pressure wave affect diffusivity?

Comment: @JonCuster there may or may not have been a standing wave in the tube. I doubt at those low frequencies that there could be a standing wave.

Comment: @JonCuster These oscillations are much lower than the natural frequency of the gas column.

Comment: Generally speaking, IMHO having physics experiments performed in a medical environment is an invitation for disaster. More to the point, we can't debug an experiment for you that happened so long ago that you vaguely remember how it was done. Your only chance: redo the experiment today and see if you get the outcome you remember.

Comment: Returning to the suggestion of a standing wave, although the fundamental mechanical frequency might be unsuitable, what about a harmonic frequency, or some other acoustic 'hum' frequency emitted by the equipment? ... I'm not giving an informed explanation.  Like CuriousOne I'm sceptical about the value of speculating about a vague observation long after the apparatus is dismantled, especially when no report of the experiment is available.

Comment: @CuriousOne I do have the equipment resources once gain to repeat the experiment. But unfortunately at present not the schedule or funding.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I really think that it should be done, by the way. It's certainly an interesting question.

Comment: Were you trying to set up traveling longitudinal waves that would increase transport?

Comment: @honeste_vivere The purported principle behind HFOV is that it promotes diffusion of gas into the lung without having to replace bulk volume. The clinical outcomes are well oxygenated patients and reduced lung energy since larger tidal volumes are not required as with more conventional ventilation methods. This purpose of this experiment was to provide scientific evidence of accelerated diffusion.

Comment: Since it is called High Freq.  Osc. Ventilation, I believe there could be a typographical  error.  Instead of 4 to 20 Hz, it is 4 to 20 KHz, or even MHz, then the 2 meter tube would be able to "house" a standing wave.  If this is the case, then the standing wave would cause a delay in diffusion,  because the oxygen molecules would spend more time colliding with the other molecules, instead of moving to the opposite side.

Comment: @Guill No, it's exactly as I wrote it. The rate is considered high frequency in HFOV relative to the more conventional intermittent mandatory ventilation where cycle rate is typically 8 to 20 breaths per minute (less than 1 Hz).