# Can a mechanical forced oscillation of a gas column significantly affect diffusion rates through the column?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, diffusion, applied-physics

[High Frequency Ventilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-frequency_ventilation) (HFV) is a special type of mechanical ventilation used in critical intensive care units. Rather than moving gas volumes in bulk at conventional breath rates, HFV operates at much higher cyclic rates with smaller stroke volumes. This seems to effectively provide the same transport of oxygen to the lungs but without imposing undue shear stress on the lungs that is often a side effect in conventional mechanical ventilation.

But to the point of my question, manufacturers and researchers seem to claim, or at least promote the idea, that HFV, by its higher more energetic rates lead to "alternative mechanisms of gas exchange ...". I'm supposing they mean accelerated gas exchange through the oscillating column.

These oscillations are on the order of less than ~ 100 mL compared to maybe several liters in the gas column connecting to the patient's lungs. From a molecular energy point of view **Can this significantly accelerate transport?**

The following picture is someone's rendition of of a 'improved' gas particle paths in the alveoli due to HFV. But aren't gas particles moving crazily fast to begin with? can 4 to 20 Hz, 50 to 100 mL oscillations really improve on that?

[image]

Comment: related : [Why would oscillation of a gas column inhibit rather than promote mixing?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/253985)

Comment: Could the flow be turbulent? Even weak turbulence can achieve significant improvement in transport over that of diffusion.

Comment: This [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4990976) might help.